# unban command with discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make an unban command but I get an error `const member;` ERROR: Missing initializer in const declaration

```js
client.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix + "unban"))
    if (!message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) {
      return message.channel.send(`You cant use this command since you're missing "BAN_MEMBERS" perm`)
    }
    if (!args[0]) return (await message.channel.send('pls enter a users id to unban.')).then(msg => msg.delete({timeout: 5000}))
    const member;
    try {
      member = await client.users.fetch(args[0])
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
      return message.channel.send(('an error accured'));
    }
const reason = args[1] ? args.slice(1).join(' ') : 'no reason';
const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setFooter(`${message.author.tag} | ${message.author.id}`, message.author.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true}))  
message.guild.fetchBans().then( bans => {
  const user = bans.find(ban => ban.user.id === member.id);
  if (user) {
    newEmbed.setTitle(`Successfully Unbanned ${user.user.tag}`)
    .setColor('#FFFF00')
    .addField({name: 'User ID', value: user.user.id, inline: true})
    .addField({name: 'User Tag', value: user.user.tag, inline: true})
    .addField({name: 'Banned Reason', value: user.reason})
    message.channel.send(newEmbed)
}})})
```

Answer (score 0):

`const` means that the variable will be immutable (constant). Thus, declaring a `const`-type variable and not immediately assigning it a value is pointless, and not allowed in Javascript.

To make a mutable variable, instead of `const`, you should use `let`.

So, in your code, line 7 should look like this:

```js
let member;
```

Comment: if I put let member; the error is: args is not defined

Comment: This checks out. You haven't defined `args` anywhere in your code. I assume you want them to be the arguments after the command invocation. For that, you can put `const args = message.content.trim().split(/ +/g);` at the top of your handler function.

Comment: I appreciate the effort you're giving me. All tho as soon as I turned the bot online, it spammed like 30 messages of an "error accured." then said in the console log  DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
 user_id: Value "error" is not snowflake.

Comment: Can you provide the full error messages via Pastebin or a similar service?

Comment: [https://i.imgur.com/qumhvUO.png](https://i.imgur.com/qumhvUO.png)